# kableExtra: Continued on Next Page for longtable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, longtable, kableextra

I am using `kableExtra` for `longtable` with the following code.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

long_dt <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)

kable(
      long_dt, 
      format    = "latex", 
      longtable = T, 
      booktabs  = T, 
      caption   = "Longtable"
      ) %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6)) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

The output is

[image]

I wonder how to add text *(Continued on Next Page ...)* at the bottom of the table if it spans to next page.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using R code.  The longtable LaTeX package supports it, but there's no way to request it using `knitr` or `kableExtra` functions.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330 for your comment. I got the required output in `R` using `xtable` ([See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220930/4821)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a kableExtra argument for that. I haven't checked but I suppose it wasn't available when the question was first posted.

From the documentation:

> repeat_header_continued: T/F or a text string. Whether or not to put a continued mark on the second page of longtable. If you put in text, we will use this text as the "continued" mark.

The default is *(continued...)* so for your specific case it would be:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

long_dt <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)

kable(
      long_dt, 
      format    = "latex", 
      longtable = T, 
      booktabs  = T, 
      caption   = "Longtable"
      ) %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6)) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
              repeat_header_continued = "\\textit{(Continued on Next Page...)}")
```

Output:

[image]